# page/video_stats - Graph API Permissions error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

i have page access token, i am administrator of the page with following granted permissions:

- manage_pages
- read_insights

However, when GET-ing this end-point trough Graph API explorer:

*me?fields=fan_count,video_stats.**metrics(['VIEWS_3S'])**&metadata=1*

i receive (**#200) Permissions error**

Anybody can please explain why? What permissions i am missing?

I would like to get basic data from Graph API (page's lifetime videos_posted, page's total videos views lifetime).

Basically those data are in facebook frontend at page/insights/videos and where you can enter custom date_preset, for example from 21 March to 21 November, then you get minutes viewed or videos viewed.

**UPDATE:**

i am able to get data from {page-id}/insights/{metric} but not from video_stats though

Comment: Can you try again using permission "read_insights" ? 
It is clearly a permission issue and you should try to understand what are you missing.

Comment: If you still have issue you could try with all permissions granted and see if it works, and then remove them step by step until won't work again. Like this you will know what permission what mandatory.

Comment: @RăducanuIonuţ Thanks for reply, unfortunately didn't work out, one more thing, i am able to get data fom {page-id}/insights/{metric} but not from video_stats

Comment: Please check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/insights#availmetrics

Comment: You can see all available metrics, and I can't see video_stats there.

At the end of the page you have Tab Types, is this what are you looking for? There you have "videos" tab where you can query specific metrics like:
me/videos?metric=page_video_views

Comment: I was talking about video_stats edge https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/video_stats/